# How to make boxplots of multiple variable in the the same graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am looking for how to make a boxplot with multiple variables. I work on species presence data following a latitudinal gradient. And I can’t get all my species boxplot on the same graphic. I used this script, but I have 42 species it will be complicated to do it one by one.

```
Euphau<- read.csv("clip_euphau_past.csv", sep=";", dec=",")

ggplot(Euphau)+
    geom_violin(aes(x=Euphau$Euphausia_crystallorophias, y = Euphau$Latitude))+
    xlab("species") +
    ylab("Latitude")
```

Here is my data:

[image]

```
   Latitude Euphausia_crystallorophias Euphausia_frigida Euphausia_longirostris Euphausia_lucens Euphausia_similis
1   -69.050                          0                 0                      0                0                 0
2   -69.052                          0                 0                      1                0                 0
3   -69.000                          0                 0                      1                0                 0
4   -68.999                          0                 1                      0                1                 0
5   -68.987                          1                 1                      0                1                 0
6   -68.980                          0                 1                      1                1                 1
7   -68.966                          0                 0                      0                0                 0
8   -68.956                          1                 0                      0                0                 1
9   -68.946                          0                 0                      0                0                 1
10  -68.945                          1                 0                      0                0                 1
11  -68.900                          0                 0                      0                0                 0
```

To summarize, I want to make a graph with a boxplot for each species according to their presence or not at latitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided much data, but is this what you're looking for?

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
pivot_longer(Euphau, -Latitude) %>%
ggplot() +
  geom_violin(aes(x=name, y = Latitude, fill = as.factor(value)))+
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("Absent","Present")) + 
    labs(x = "Species", y = "Latitude", fill = "") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it is because my database is really very large (6955 lines...) Otherwise yes this is what I want to do.

Comment: No I have a problem with the function : pivot_longer

Comment: Could you provide additional details?

Comment: This is the tidyr package that I cannot install, my Rstudio bug